# Installation Ubuntu 16.04: emergency mode booting after Bluetooth conflict

Tags: boot, 16.04, bluetooth

I have just installed Ubuntu 16.04 with a dual-boot system in my Acer laptop. The GRUB interface shows up regularly and as I go into Ubuntu, just after the filesystem check, the system gives the following message in console mode:

> Welcome to emergency mode! After logging in, type "journalctl -xb" to view system logs, "systemctl reboot" to reboot, "systemctl default" or ^D to try again to boot into default mode. Press Enter for maintenance (or press control D to continue): **[25.157385 Bluetooth: hci0 : BCM : reading local version info failed (-110)**

Trying to reboot or proceed in default mode leads brings again to the same point. Effectively, I can't seem to move on any further.

Question: how to fix this and load Ubuntu 16.04?

Note: During installation I gave permission to install third-party software, if this piece of information is relevant.

Comment: Well... the whole issue healed up by itself. I happened to reboot the system several times while I was checking whether the issue depended on different efi boot loaders (Ubuntu 16.04 comes with a foursome) and whether Windows loaded up correctly. After the third reboot or so the Bluetooth message already disappeared and, after another few rounds, I was presented with the regular log-in screen. I leave the post in place in case this may support other users.

Comment: The issue appeared again out of the blue. It may be incidental but it appeared after I hadn't used the laptop for a few weeks. This problem seems part of a syndrome of issues that Ubuntu 16.06 has with bluetooth (as of this post) and with the encrypted file system (see for example http://askubuntu.com/questions/855894/16-04-log-in-denied-with-error-home-user-ecryptfs-does-not-exist). The issue is open. My current solution strategy for this laptop is to reinstall 14.04 and save me a lot of hassle.